# jquery: changing class (but not) changing action

Tags: jquery, class, buttonclick

I found a strange behaviour.. surely is know but I do not know how to fix it.

I have a button that has to do 2 different actions depending on the current class.

When clicked, it toggles its class, in this way, at next click will make a different action..
but it continues to perform the "old" action, like class has not been changed

To be more clear...

> here the relative [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7arkvehf/)

you can see that when you click button `A` it writes `AAA` and the two buttons toggle their class (since colors has changed): therefore it seems all OK

But if you click again button `A` instead of writing `BBB` that is what should happen when `class b` button is pressed, it again writes `AAA`

Clearly can have 2 buttons for the 2 action and toggle the 2 buttons instead of exchanging the class, but I would like to understand if I'm doing something wrong or the reason of this strange behaviour.

Regards

Comment: The key point here is that you have bound the event handler to the **element**. Changing the value of an attribute of the element (the class in this case) does not affect which event handlers are bound to it.

Comment: Yes this was clear also for me but did not know how to handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use event delegation as you are adding and removing classes which are used for binding events:

```
$('body').on('click','.a',function(){
    $('#R').html('AAA');
    $('#A').addClass('b').removeClass('a');
    $('#B').addClass('a').removeClass('b');
});
$('body').on('click','.b',function(){
    $('#R').html('BBB');
    $('#B').addClass('b').removeClass('a');
    $('#A').addClass('a').removeClass('b');
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cL0cvr5w/)**

Comment: OK, thanks a lot did not know event delegation.. but why downvoted? is it such a bad question?

Comment: @Joe: Not the one who downvoted.but you have not added the code in question.

Comment: Well, I made a fiddle to fully show it, anyway, never mind: important is to solve the issue, and your suggestion did it.

Comment: @Joe: glad it helps :)